# replace asterisks in dataframe with NA's

Tags: r

Here's my dataframe df

I'm trying:

```
df=data.frame(rbind(c(1,"*","*"),c("*",3,"*"))
df2=as.data.frame(sapply(df,sub,pattern="*",replacement="NA"))
```

It doesn't work because of the asterisk but I'm getting mad trying to replace it.

Comment: double backslash is the secret to escaping special characters like the asterisk, have a look here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing

Comment: @Ben thanks I take note of this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put up a full reproducible example, people will be more inclined to help when you make it easy for em. Anywho...

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,'*',3,4), b=c('*',2,3,4,'*'))
> dat
  a b
1 1 *
2 2 2
3 * 3
4 3 4
5 4 *
> as.data.frame(sapply(dat,sub,pattern='\\*',replacement=NA))
     a    b
1    1 <NA>
2    2    2
3 <NA>    3
4    3    4
5    4 <NA>
```

Comment: cheers Arun, don't get nearly enough time to put posts together :/ have twins on the way in a month so that won't really help haha

Answer (score 8):

If you just have `*` in (meaning its not like `ab*de`) your `data.frame`, then, you can do ths without `regex`:

```
df[df == "*"] <- NA
```

Answer (score 8):

Both solutions here address an object already in your workplace. If possible (or at least in the future) you can make use of the `na.strings` argument in `read.table`. Notice that it is *plural* "strings", so you should be able to specify more than one character to treat as `NA` values.

Here's an example: This just writes a file named "readmein.txt" to your current working directory and verifies that it is there.

```
cat("V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7\n
2 * * * * * 2\n
1 2 * * * * 1\n", file = "readmein.txt")
list.files(pattern = "readme")
# [1] "readmein.txt"
```

Here's `read.table` with the `na.strings` argument in action.

```
read.table("readmein.txt", na.strings="*", header = TRUE)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
# 1  2 NA NA NA NA NA  2
# 2  1  2 NA NA NA NA  1
```

### Update: Objects already in your workplace

I see another problem with the other two answers: They both result in character (or rather factor) variables, even when the column should have possibly been numeric.

Here's an example. First, we create an example dataset. For fun, I've added another character to be treated as `NA`: ".".

```
temp <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(1:3),
  V2 = c(1, "*", 3),
  V3 = c("a", "*", "c"),
  V4 = c(".", "*", "3"))
temp
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  1  a  .
# 2  2  *  *  *
# 3  3  3  c  3
str(temp)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ V1: int  1 2 3
#  $ V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "*","1","3": 2 1 3
#  $ V3: Factor w/ 3 levels "*","a","c": 2 1 3
#  $ V4: Factor w/ 3 levels ".","*","3": 1 2 3
```

Let's make a copy, and then solve this in what I would consider the most obvious "R" way:

```
temp1 <- temp
temp1[temp1 == "*"|temp1 == "."] <- NA
```

*Looks* OK...

```
temp1
#   V1   V2   V3   V4
# 1  1    1    a <NA>
# 2  2 <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 3  3    3    c    3
```

... but I presume that V2 and V4 should have been numeric....

```
str(temp1)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ V1: int  1 2 3
#  $ V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "*","1","3": 2 NA 3
#  $ V3: Factor w/ 3 levels "*","a","c": 2 NA 3
#  $ V4: Factor w/ 3 levels ".","*","3": 1 NA 3
```

Here's a workaround:

```
temp2 <- read.table(text = capture.output(temp), na.strings = c("*", "."))
temp2
#   V1 V2   V3 V4
# 1  1  1    a NA
# 2  2 NA <NA> NA
# 3  3  3    c  3
str(temp2)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ V1: int  1 2 3
#  $ V2: int  1 NA 3
#  $ V3: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","c": 1 NA 2
#  $ V4: int  NA NA 3
```

### Update 2: (Yet another) alternative

It might be more appropriate to make use of `type.convert` which is described as a "helper function for `read.table`" on its help page. I haven't timed it, but my guess is that it would be faster than the workaround I mentioned above, with all the benefits.

```
data.frame(
  lapply(temp, function(x) type.convert(
    as.character(x), na.strings = c("*", "."))))
```

Comment: Using the last approach (Update 2), I get `NA` or `<NA>` depending on what other entries the row contains, e.g. `V1 = c(1, "*", "1")` versus `V1 = c(1, "*", "a")`... Thus, with your temp data.frame I get `2 NA <NA> NA`

Comment: @PatrickT, I'm not sure that I understand your comment. The point I'm trying to make in this answer is exactly that each column should generally be treated individually in determining how to deal with missing values. Can you elaborate on your comment?

Answer (score 1):

This could work (It's a pretty flexible) but there's other great solutions already.  Arun's solution is my typical approach but created `replacer` for new R (little experience with the command line) users.  I wouldn't recommend `replacer` for anyone with even a bit of experience.

```
library(qdap)
replacer(dat, "*", NA)
```